# Probabilities when picking from two urns

Tags: probability, probability-theory, polya-urn-model

Assume there are two urns with 4 balls each. Each ball has a certain probability to be picked. For example:

**Urn1:**

- Ball A: 0.7
- Ball B: 0.1
- Ball C: 0.1
- Ball D: 0.1

**Urn2:**

- Ball E: 0.3
- Ball F: 0.2
- Ball G: 0.25
- Ball H: 0.25

Notice the numbers next to the balls indicate the pick probability (e.g. there's a chance of 0.7 to pick Ball A when picking from Urn1).

My question is then: When 5 balls from each urn are picked, what's the probability for the event

> Z=(*A* and *E* were picked at least once OR *C* and *G* were
> picked at least once)

i.e. what's the probability for P(Z)?

**To clarify what I mean here are some example sequences:**

> picked from Urn1 = {A, A, C, D, A}
>
> picked from Urn2 = {H, H, F, H, F}

***A*** was picked from Urn1 but ***E*** was not from Urn2. ***C*** was picked from Urn1 but ***G*** was not from Urn2. Therefore the event Z did not occur.

> picked from Urn1 = {A, A, A, D, A}
>
> picked from Urn2 = {E, G, H, G, H}

***A*** was picked from Urn1 and ***E*** from Urn2. Therefore the event Z occurred.

> picked from Urn1 = {A, C, A, D, A}
>
> picked from Urn2 = {E, G, H, G, H}

***A*** was picked from Urn1 and ***E*** from Urn2. Additionally, ***C*** was picked from Urn1 and ***G*** from Urn2. Therefore the event Z occurred.

> picked from Urn1 = {B, C, D, B, C}
>
> picked from Urn2 = {G, G, H, H, H}

***A*** was not picked from Urn1. However, ***C*** was picked from Urn1 and ***G*** from Urn2. Therefore the event Z occurred.

Comment: So it's with replacement then?

Comment: Yes, with replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(A)$ represent the probability that $A$ will be picked among the five balls from the first urn; similarly for $P(C), P(E), P(G)$.

And let $P(A\wedge E)$
represent the probability that $A$ and $E$ are both chosen, $P(A\vee C)$ represent the probability that either $A$ or $C$ was chosen, and similarly for letters other than $A$ and $E$ or $C$.

What we want is $$P((A\wedge E) \vee (C\wedge G))$$
This is almost the same as 
$P(A\wedge E) + P (C\wedge G)$ but one would have double-counted cases where all of $A,C,E,G$ were chosen.  Thus
 $$P((A\wedge E) \vee (C\wedge G)) = P(A\wedge E) + P (C\wedge G) - P(A\wedge C \wedge E\wedge G)$$

Now we can use the fact that the two urns happenings are completely independent to write this as 
$$P((A\wedge E) \vee (C\wedge G)) = P(A) \cdot P(E)  + P(C) \cdot P(G)  - P(A\wedge C) \cdot P(E \wedge G)$$

$P(A)$ is easy:  The probability of $A$ not being chosen is $(1-0.7)^5$ so 
$P(A) = 1 - (0.3)^5 = 0.99757$

Similarly $$P(E) = 1-(1-0.7)^5=0.83193 \\ P(C) = 1-(1-0.9)^5=0.40951\\P(G) = 1-(1-0.75)^5=0.7626953125 
$$

We still have not found $P(A\wedge C)$ or  $P(E \wedge G)$ and these are not a simple matter of multiplying individual probabilities, because the probability of getting a $C$ is different if we know that at least one pick was an $A$.  We can get  $P(A\wedge C)$  by the trick based on calculating  $P(A \vee C)$ as follows:
$$
P(A \vee C) = 1 - P(\lnot(A \vee C)) = 1 - (1-[0.7+0.1])^5 = 1-(0.2)^5 = 0.99968
\\
P(A \vee  C) = P(A) + P(C) - P(A \wedge C) \\
P(A \wedge C) =  P(A) + P(C) - P(A \vee  C) = 0.4074
$$
and
$$
P(E \vee G) = 1 - P(\lnot(E \vee G) = 1 - (1-[0.3+0.25])^5 = 1-(0.45)^5 \approx 0.981547 
\\
P(E \wedge G) =  P(E) + P(G) - P(E \vee  G) \approx 0.61307804074
$$
Putting it all together we have 
$$
P((A\wedge E) \vee (C\wedge G)) = P(A) \cdot P(E)  + P(C) \cdot P(G)  - P(A\wedge C) \cdot P(E \wedge G) \\
\approx 0.892472
$$

Comment: Don't you mean $P\left((A\wedge E) \vee (C\wedge G)\right)$ instead of $P(A\wedge E) \vee (C\wedge G)$? Or perhaps $P(A\wedge E) \vee P(C\wedge G)$?

Comment: Thanks @Mark great response. I kind of hoped the solution wasn't that complex so a general formula could be applied those kind of problems (e.g. if adding another pair like G,H or put more balls into each urn, etc.). However, it doesn't seem like so.

Comment: Yes, I consistently left off the outer parentheses in the "what we want" probability. Hopefully the meaning is clear, since the alternative interpretation would be a probability times an event, which is ill-formed. I have edited in the extra parenst; it appears in five places.